# Voting buttons and quote blocks scroll over the top of review queue banner

Tags: bug, review

I was just reviewing a first post on RPG.se and noticed some strange UI behavior. As I scrolled down the voting buttons and quote blocks scroll on-top of the banner instead of below. See screenshots below.

I first noticed it with the voting buttons:

[image]
[image]

But quote blocks also do it:

[image]